# Checking a superclass/interface method and an overridden method for equality

Tags: java, reflection

I've run into a situation where I have a `Method` instance from an interface definition and a `Method` instance of the same method from an implementing class.

For example:

```
public interface Foo {
    void bar();
}

public class FooImpl implements Foo {
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("foobar");
    }
}
```

Using reflection, I have obtained a `Method` instance of `bar` from the `Foo` interface and its derived implementation from `FooImpl`. Essentially, I need to consider these `Methods` equal, but obviously the `equals` method indicates they are not equivalent.

Specifically, I need a way to determine if a given `Method` obtained through reflection overrides a superclass/interface `Method`.

I'm currently using a workaround which avoids the situation completely by finding the "least-derived" method from a given class, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: do you need this at runtime? Otherwise documentation should solve this problem using the `@Override` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't taken the modifiers into consideration in the equals method but this should get you reasonably close if you want to use this algorithm:

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestFooBar {
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Get the class of interest
        Class fooImpl = Class.forName("test.FooImpl");

        // Test all the methods
        for(Method m : fooImpl.getMethods()) {
            boolean overriden = false;
            List<Class> parents = new ArrayList<Class>();
            for(Class c : fooImpl.getInterfaces()) {
                parents.add(c);
            }
            if(fooImpl.getSuperclass() != null) parents.add(fooImpl.getSuperclass());
            for(Class c : fooImpl.getInterfaces()) {
                for(Method sm : c.getMethods()) {
                    if(equals(sm, m)) {
                        overriden = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(overriden) break;
            }
            System.out.println(m+": "+(overriden ? "Overriden" : "Not overriden"));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static boolean equals(Method m1, Method m2) {
    if(!m1.getName().equals(m2.getName())) return false;
    String t1 = "";
    for(Class c : m1.getParameterTypes()) {
        t1+=c.getName()+"/";
    }
    String t2 = "";
    for(Class c : m2.getParameterTypes()) {
        t2+=c.getName()+"/";
    }
    if(!t1.equals(t2)) return false;

    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I considered simply checking the method names and parameter types, but was hoping there was a more comprehensive way.

Comment: Well, the methods aren't equal (from an object standpoint at least). They are only logically equal based on the conditions you set forth so unfortunately you can't get around having to implement those conditions in an algorithm.

Comment: I came across this problem but I was also working with generics and there it gets a lot worse: In the Interface you'll find a method with return types / parameters "java.lang.Object". In the implementing class you'll find a method with the same signature (Object) but another one having the return/parameter types based on your generic definitions. Oh, and you don't get them because you call "getMethods()"; "getDeclaredMethods()" will return both methods as well.